# Magento v1.7 - admin can not receive email after new order is arriving

Tags: magento

I would like the store administrator receive email notification after new order is arriving.

**Here is my setting**
[image]

However, it doesn't work.

Is there anyone can help me?

BTW, others emails sending is working perfectly, so there is no problem on SMTP server setting.

Comment: @ivantedja, user got the email

Comment: @DHC I had similar problem. As I see you use custom template for "New Order Confirmation Template", that's saved in the DB. Do you receive confirmation emails, when guest customers complete an order? Can you also do the next experiment: In admin area go to System -> Transactional Emails. Check if your email template is exists in the displayed grid view.

Answer (score 1):

There is a problem with the mail setup and my advice is to ask the support desk of your hosting company to do you a little favour in fixing it. This is because I don't know your operating system and I cannot therefore send you a link to what you need to do. Besides, the support desk will have fixed this problem before and they should be able to do it in minutes.

Imagine your server has an 'A' record of example.com. When your email goes out the email to the customer gets sent out onto the ether whereas with your email to me@example.com the server says 'hey! that's for us! That can stop right here!' and it delivers it to the local mailbox. So, for the purposes of mail, your email server needs to make sure it isn't forwarding it to localdomain. The setting is probably quite simple for that, but, without knowing your hosting, I would recommend calling a favour from support.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to get a copy of the transaction email,

Go to Admin Panel-> System -> Configuration -> Sales Email tab ->Order -> Specify your email id in the option **Send an Email copy**.

This will help you.

Regards 
Vikk

Comment: So, he has not specified the `Send an Email copy` you mentioned? Can you tell, which part from System > Configuration did he capture in the screenshot?